# How can I do a recursive find and replace from the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, find-and-replace

Using a shell like bash or zshell, how can I do a recursive 'find and replace'? In other words, I want to replace every occurrence of 'foo' with 'bar' in all files in this directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: An alternative answer for the same questions can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704020/recursive-search-and-replace-on-mac-and-linux

Comment: Related: [Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1583219/435605)

Comment: It might be a good idea to try this in vim. That way you can use the confirmation feature to make sure you don't swap something you don't intend to. I am not sure if it can be done directory wide.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

This command will do it (tested on both Mac OS X Lion and Kubuntu Linux).

```
# Recursively find and replace in files
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Here's how it works:

1. `find . -type f -name '*.txt'` finds, in the current directory (`.`) and below, all regular files (`-type f`) whose names end in `.txt`
2. `|` passes the output of that command (a list of filenames) to the next command
3. `xargs` gathers up those filenames and hands them one by one to `sed`
4. `sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g'` means "edit the file in place, without a backup, and make the following substitution (`s/foo/bar`) multiple times per line (`/g`)" (see `man sed`)

Note that the 'without a backup' part in line 4 is OK for me, because the files I'm changing are under version control anyway, so I can easily undo if there was a mistake.

To avoid having to remember this, I use an interactive bash script, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# find_and_replace.sh

echo "Find and replace in current directory!"
echo "File pattern to look for? (eg '*.txt')"
read filepattern
echo "Existing string?"
read existing
echo "Replacement string?"
read replacement
echo "Replacing all occurences of $existing with $replacement in files matching $filepattern"

find . -type f -name $filepattern -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e "s/$existing/$replacement/g"
```

Comment: Never ever pipe find output to xargs without the `-print0` option. Your command will fail on files with spaces etc. in their name.

Comment: Why do you need `sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g'`? Doesn't `sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'` do the same thing?

Comment: Also, just `find -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +` will do all this with GNU find.

Comment: @DanielAndersson - I seem to be getting different results on my work Mac and home Ubuntu machines, so I need to do some more tinkering before I update this answer. One note, though: the `find... -exec` method is interesting, but `man find` says to use '-execdir' instead for security reasons.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that remark on `-execdir` in the manual, but I have never been or heard of anyone who has been bitten, so until then I stay with `-exec` :-) . That you get different results on Mac OS X and Ubuntu is because Mac OS X does not come with `GNU find` as standard, and `-exec +` and the omission of the path are `GNU find` specific extensions. Perhaps the same could explain some `sed` discrepancies between the systems.

Comment: @DanielAndersson - It appears that you're correct; my Linux box can do the `find... -exec` version, but my Mac can't. `sed - 's/foo/bar/g'` does not work; `-i` is to provide a backup file extension, and giving it an empty string means 'don't back up.' The command in my answer works on both platforms.

Comment: I get `sed: can't read : No such file or directory` when I run `find . -name '*.md' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/&auml;/ä/g'`, but `find . -name '*.md' -print0` gives a list of many files.

Comment: This works for me if I remove the space between the `-i` and the `''`

Comment: What is the meaning of `''` after the `sed -i` what is the `''` role?

Comment: @Jas: `-i` with `sed` means perform an in-place edit and `''` (empty string) means don't create backups. If you did `sed -i '.bak'` the original files would be preserved with a `.bak` extension.

Comment: what does `-print0` do?

Comment: I don't like this solution, as for me, it 'touches' every .txt file and bumps the file modification time, even if no changes are made...

Comment: `sed: can't read : No such file or directory`

Comment: I am getting following error: `sed: can't read : No such file or directory`

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/677078/sed-cant-read-no-such-file-or-directory for a solution to the `no such file or directory` error

Comment: @KarlMorrison I got the same error. I replaced "print0" with "print" and it worked.

Answer (score 63):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i'' -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

This removes the `xargs` dependency.

Comment: This does not work with GNU `sed`, so will fail on most systems. GNU `sed` requires you to put no space between `-i` and `''`.

Comment: The accepted answers does a better job of explaining it. but +1 for using the correct syntax.

Comment: `-i''` is exactly the same as `-i`.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Git then you can do this:

```
git grep -lz foo | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

`-l` lists only filenames. `-z` prints a null byte after each result.

I ended up doing this because some files in a project did not have a newline at the end of the file, and sed added a newline even when it made no other changes. (No comment on whether or not files should have a newline at the end. )

Comment: Big +1 for this solution. The rest of the `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 sed ...` solutions not only take a lot longer but also add newlines to files that don't have one already, which is a nuisance when working inside a git repo. `git grep` is lighting fast by comparison.

Comment: Not sure what the single quote pair does in the sed command.  I think it was causing a "no such file" error.  Worked great without them.

Comment: May be a difference between gnu sed and other sed implementations.

Comment: This brought down the time taken for my script from 7 minutes to 40 seconds! Thank you for this solution

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' $(find . -type f)
```

Tested on Ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT:

This command will NOT work if subdirectory names and/or filenames contain spaces, but if you do have them don't use this command as it won't work.

It is generally a bad practice to use spaces in directory names and filenames.

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0020.php

Look at "Important facts about file names"

Comment: Try it when you have file(s) with space(s) in their names.  (There's a rule of thumb that says, "If something seems too good to be true, it probably is."  If you have "discovered" a solution that's more compact than anything anybody else has posted in 3½ years, you should ask yourself why that might be.)

Comment: Files with spaces are fairly uncommon in linux. Fair to list the caveat but IMO this is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my zsh/perl function I use for this:

```
change () {
        from=$1 
        shift
        to=$1 
        shift
        for file in $*
        do
                perl -i.bak -p -e "s{$from}{$to}g;" $file
                echo "Changing $from to $to in $file"
        done
}
```

And I'd execute it using

```
$ change foo bar **/*.java
```

(for example)

Answer (score 2):

### Use This Shell Script

I now use this shell script, which combines things I learned from the other answers and from searching the web. I placed it in a file called `change` in a folder on my `$PATH` and did `chmod +x change`.

```
#!/bin/bash
function err_echo {
  >&2 echo "$1"
}

function usage {
  err_echo "usage:"
  err_echo '  change old new foo.txt'
  err_echo '  change old new foo.txt *.html'
  err_echo '  change old new **\*.txt'
  exit 1
}

[ $# -eq 0 ] && err_echo "No args given" && usage

old_val=$1
shift
new_val=$1
shift
files=$* # the rest of the arguments

[ -z "$old_val" ]  && err_echo "No old value given" && usage
[ -z "$new_val" ]  && err_echo "No new value given" && usage
[ -z "$files" ]    && err_echo "No filenames given" && usage

for file in $files; do
  sed -i '' -e "s/$old_val/$new_val/g" $file
done
```

Comment: so which of your two answers you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

My use case was I wanted to replace 
`foo:/Drive_Letter` with `foo:/bar/baz/xyz`
In my case I was able to do it with the following code.
I was in the same directory location where there were bulk of files.

```
find . -name "*.library" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/foo:\/Drive_Letter:/foo:\/bar\/baz\/xyz/g'
```

hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked fine on Ubuntu and CentOS; however, under OS X I kept getting errors:

```
find . -name Root -exec sed -i 's/1.2.3.4\/home/foo.com\/mnt/' {} \;
```

> sed: 1: "./Root": invalid command code .

When I tried passing the params via xargs it worked fine with no errors:

```
find . -name Root -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/1.2.3.4\/home/foo.com\/mnt/'
```

Comment: The fact that you changed `-i` to `-i ''` is probably more relevant than the fact that you changed `-exec` to `-print0 | xargs -0`.  BTW, you probably don't need the `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Recursively find and replace in files
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

The above worked like a charm, but with linked directories, I've to add `-L` flag to it. The final version looks like:

```
# Recursively find and replace in files
find -L . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using zsh globbing and `sed`

(Tested with `sed` on MacOS - may vary a bit on Linux)

`sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g' somefolder/**/*.txt`